# How can I get reduction dimensionality with sklearn PCA when I have more features than rows?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I am working in a project and I have to read a csv file that has more columns than rows. When I use PCA from sklearn with a csv that has more rows than features, it works well, but now that I have more features, when I use pca().fit_transform(), it returns a square matrix which has the number of columns equal to the total of rows. How can I get all elements?

Answer (score 1):

If there are n observations with p variables, then the number of distinct principal components is min(n-1,p).

See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)